# Electronics book for physics undergraduates

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering, signal-processing

I am  going through very hard time studying electronics, I studied little electronics at high school (what is diode, transistor, etc). Now in clg now I need electronics to study, I don't understand anything at all, I find electronics very hard and also boring.
So please suggest me a absolute beginner book in electronics, one that is suitable for physics majors, I searched "electrical engineering stack exchange", but those books don't match my syllabus also looks like engineering book. My syllabus include OPAM, negative feedback, positive feedback all these stuff.

Comment: Have you checked out the relevant chapters in Sears and Zemansky's University Physics? It's most EM stuff, but some basic circuitry stuff as well.

Comment: Actually my syllabus is far more advanced than university physics book

Comment: Includes OPAM,feed back,transistor ,diode etc etc

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Electrical engineering might be a good forum but the fact is that many experimental physicists need a working knowledge of practical electronics.  It is for this very reason that such courses, usually based on the text "Art of Electronics" are provided by physics departments.  When I was an undergrad 50 years ago, the physics department offered an Electronics course that was OK but but also in a much simpler world than today.  Back then, OP Amps and IC devices were just in their beginning emergent versions so Electronics courses were easier and simpler.

Comment: If you find electronics boring, then just work your way trough the five completely trivial things they require you to learn and forget about the rest. No big deal. OTOH, if you are having problems with these trivial concepts, I am a bit curious how you are doing on the rest of the material, which is significantly harder?

Comment: @Curious one :Actually I don't have good teachers ,also I am studying electronics for the 1st time,I am theoretical physics oriented guy,I enjoy studying Quantum,statistical ,classical mechanics ,but weak in electronics.

Comment: My book says,OPAMP is a general purpose linear integrated circuit.I don't even understand ,what he means by linear integrated circuit.Thats the problem ,I am not familiar with the terms even.

Comment: I still don't get it why electronics is hard when you can do quantum mechanics. What's hard about memorizing $R=U/I$ and a diode transfer function, which is really just an exponential? If you understand energy and charge conservation, then Kirchhoff's laws are obvious. A linear model for a feedback circuit is a second order differential equation. It's actually the same differential equation that you had to learn for the harmonic oscillator, to be precise. Nobody will ever ask you to do serious electronics design, trust me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Art of Electronics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Art-Electronics-Paul-Horowitz/dp/0521809266/ref=dp_ob_title_bk), now in its 3rd edition by Horowitz and Hill has always been a classic. Comprehensive and easy to read with an emphasis on practice rather than deep theory.

I am a professional electronics engineer and I have used it (I transitioned from physics) for decades

Comment: AoE may not emphasize theory, and it may not delve deeply into theory, but the first two chapters opened my eyes to the _importance_ of theory---to the _utility_ of theory---in a way that several "serious" textbooks (e.g., Senturia & Wedlock) never could do.

Comment: @jameslarge: That's because you never took a serious EE book seriously. There is a reason why they are written they way they are, just like our physics books to the EE students look like magical compendia they can never understand. One has to take the theory classes with these books to get their structure.

Comment: @CuriousOne As a professional EE I disagree. In 30 years I have never had to delve into any of the conventional EE theory as taught beyond that of AoE. The only exception was DSP, which is a rather specialist subject.

Comment: @DirkBruere: Then you never had to handle a serious EE problem outside of signal processing. That's not unusual for engineers. I can do most of my designs pi times thumb, too... until I hit the one that I can't, and then I consult the theory. Independently of the frequency of such events, I acknowledge that the theory exists and that it needs to be part of quality education.

Comment: @CuriousOne That's what a professional does i.e. not waste time on irrelevant theory until necessary. My advice to anyone is to ditch the bulk of the theory beyond AoE until needed and use the time saved to study C++

Comment: @DirkBruere: Then you get a programmer who can't do anything but trivial EE problems and he/she probably won't even do those well. If you want a programmer for a job, get a programmer, for heaven's sake. That's a specialty onto itself and EEs usually don't make good ones, either. Neither do physicists, by the way... :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne Most EE jobs these days require knowledge of embedded. That means C and/or C++. Pure EE jobs are rare unless they are very specialist.

Comment: @DirkBruere: No offense, but writing embedded code is not serious EE work. I know that we all do it for a living from time to time, but serious EEs are designing wireless communications systems or they are building 250MW electrical generators. You don't do those kinds of things by repetitive application of the 90+ keywords of an aging and pretty boring programming language.

Comment: @CuriousOne There is a HUGE distinction between electrical engineers and electronics engineers. Anyone who is an electronics engineer will be spending much of their career writing code. No code, no job.

Comment: @DirkBruere: I have known plenty of EEs who could code and do real work. OTOH, you are right, there is also the type who should rather call themselves embedded programmer, since they nearly faint when they have to touch a non-trivial circuit. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer suggesting "Art of Electronics" is spot on -- no argument.  However, it is also spot on expensive.  An alternative is [Practical Electronics For Inventors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1259587541) which is now in its 4th edition and an excellent low priced book that allows you to move through the material more quickly.

The scope of coverage for "Practical Electronics For Inventors" is about the same as "Art of Electronics" but it is not as deep in a number of areas but definitely more practical and hands-on giving the reader ready-made "experience" to go along with the knowledge.

I own both and I would recommend both but if money is tight, go for "Practical Electronics for Inventors" or just buy it first to see if it works for you.

Comment: They are both giant blockbusters capable of breaking your toes if you drop them!

Comment: The "Art of electronics" is a hobbyist version of electronics engineering. While popular it is completely inadequate to do serious experimental work today. I don't know the other book, but if it's even more shallow, it's probably good as a door stop.

Comment: @CuriousOne  -- I am curious, what's missing from "Art of Electronics"?  Even though I started out as an EE, I quickly switched to Physics but  still kept a hand in EE Electronics courses due to my hobby of amateur "Ham" radio.  I have built lots of stuff over the last 50 years.  Designed and build my own dual-811 linear amplifier when I was in high-school.  Built my own transmitter from scratch (junior-high and high-school) and of course lots of stuff since.  For someone who is not wanting an EE degree, these books are not bad and can carry a person quite a ways.  Thus, What's Missing?

Comment: What is missing is the entire non-trivial section of the EE library, which you, as EE student, should have seen (and not just 50 years ago).

Comment: So, you are saying that since this book (AoE) does not cover every topic of an EE 4 year course, it is not an adequate reference and tutorial for electronics.  I have many books in my library on EE subjects -- electronics (analog and digital), micro-electronics, and integrated circuit design, RF engineering,  power systems analysis), and digital signal processing and I will agree that the one book Art of Electronics does not include all those others, but it is a very good start proven by the fact that it is the number 1 selected Electronics course text for undergrad and grad science majors.